# Pointer to member variable

Tags: c++

The following program output is always 1 1 1. In "Inside the c++ object model" book, it is mentioned that it will give offset. The purpose is also to find out object layout. But, I am confused with the output. Used g++ 4.5.2

```
class Test
{
    public:
        float a;
        float b;
        float c;
};

int main()
{
    float Test::*ptr = &Test::a;
    float Test::*ptr1 = &Test::b;
    float Test::*ptr2 = &Test::c;
    cout<<ptr<<endl;
    cout<<ptr1<<endl;
    cout<<ptr2<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
1
1
```

Edit(Follow up question):
In the book it is mentioned that `origin.y = 0` can be transformed to `&origin + (Point3d::y-1)` where origin is an object to Point3d and y is member variable of class Point3d. Though When I compiled it gave me compilation error.

Comment: `cout` doesn't have overloaded insertion operator for member pointers , so `ptr` gets converted to `bool` implicitly

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wrote that you wanted to find the memory offset. While what FredOverflow writes is completely true, you should make an instance of your class `Test` if you want to know the address of `a`,`b` and `c`. For instance:

```
Test t;
float *ptr = &t.a;
float *ptr1 = &t.b;
float *ptr2 = &t.c;
```

On my machine this yields the following three addresses:

```
0x7fff564f8918
0x7fff564f891c
0x7fff564f8920
```

And you will notice that they are 4 bytes (or `sizeof(float)`) apart and that the size of a `Test` is 12 bytes (using `sizeof(Test)`). Furthermore, the address of `&t` is `0x7fff564f8918` the same address of `&t.a`. That's how the memory layout of an instance of the class `Test` is  formed.

You can also find the offset of members of a `POD` type by using `offsetof()`.

```
cout << offsetof(Test, a) << endl;
cout << offsetof(Test, b) << endl;
cout << offsetof(Test, c) << endl;
```

Yields

```
0
4
8
```

Note that `offsetof(Test, b)` is essentially the same as

```
(unsigned long long) &(((Test*) 0)->b) - (unsigned long long) (Test*) 0
```

**Answer to your followup question:**

That code will not work because of the same errors as previously mentioned. However, if you wanted to calculate the address of your `y` member of `origin` and assign it the value `0` it can be done thusly:

```
class Point3d {
public:
  float x, y, z;
};

Point3d origin;
origin.y = 10;

// We take the address of origin, which points to the first member, 
// then add the offset to the member y.
float *ptr = (float*) ((unsigned long long) &origin + offsetof(Point3d, y));
cout <<  "Old value: " << *ptr << endl;
*ptr = 0;
cout <<  "New value: " << *ptr << endl;
```

Yields the output:

```
Old value: 10
New value: 0
```

Again remember that this is only possible because `Point3d` is a `POD` type.

Comment: In the book "Inside the c++ object model" it is clearly mentioned that it will give offset value. But even when i am trying to compare those pointers or doing any binary operations it is throwing me errors. I am confused whether it is due to gcc or my wrong interpretation !!!!

Comment: I added an answer to your followup question.

Answer (score 20):

You cannot print pointers to members, but pointers to members can implicitly be converted to `bool`, and those can be printed, of course. The null pointer is converted to `false`, and all other pointers are converted to `true`. By default, `std::cout` prints `false` as `0` and `true` as `1`.